# _() or {% trans %} in Django templates?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

In Django templates, you can use either `{{ _("Hello World") }}` or `{% trans "Hello World" %}` to mark strings to be translated. In docs, the “official” approach seems to be the [`{% trans %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) tag, but the `_()` syntax is mentioned too [once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters).

**How these approaches differ** (except syntax) and why should be one preferable rather than the other?

One difference is that you obviously can't use `{% trans %}` with tags and filters. But does that mean that I can just use `_()` everywhere, like `{{ _("String") }}`? It works and looks much cleaner and more consistent than using `{% trans "String" %}` with standalone strings and `_()` with tags and filters.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

So it seems that there's technically no difference as of Django 1.5. Template engine internally marks a variable for translation (by setting its `translate` attribute) in two cases:

- when you do `{% trans VAR %}` (see [`TranslateNode`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/templatetags/i18n.py#L85)), or
- if the name of a variable starts with `_(` and ends with `)` (see [`Variable.__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/template/base.py#L706)).

Later, when the variable is being [resolved](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/template/base.py#L724), Django wraps it with `ugettext` or `pgettext` if it sees the `translate` attribute.

However, as can be seen from source code, there are some flexibility considerations in favor of `{% trans %}` tag:

- you can do `{% trans "String" noop %}`, which will put the string for translation into .po files, but won't actually translate the output when rendering (no internal `translate` attribute on variable, no `ugettext` call);
- you can specify message context<sup>*</sup>, like `{% trans "May" context "verb" %}`;
- you can put translated message into a variable for later use<sup>*</sup>, like `{% trans "String" as
  translated_string %}`.

<sup>* As of Django 1.4.</sup>

Please feel free to correct me or post a better answer in case I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

The trans template tag calls the *ugettext()* function. In Django *_()* is an alias to *ugettext()*.
This is covered in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-python-code).

Comment: I'm aware that `_()` is used, by convention, as an alias to `ugettext()` _in Python code_, but not in templates. And since we all don't put something like `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _` in our templates, it's unclear how exactly does the underscore work.